# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My application gets addresses from a file that is updated every couple of hours and geocodes them and puts them on google maps.

I'm getting a OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status even though I have not used it since the day before and I'm putting time between each query. I'm putting 2 seconds between each query, this code is used when the function it is in is called which is called after 2 seconds after it's been called before.

```
var xmlhttp
var status;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var lAddress = tAddress.replace(/ /g, " +");


xmlhttp.open("GET","http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + lAddress +"&sensor=false", false);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){

        var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        status = result.status;


        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            precise[index].found = 1;
            precise[index].lat = result.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            precise[index].lng = result.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            precise[index].addr = tAddress;

        }
        else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
            alert("Search limit reached. Please try again tomorrow.");
        }
    }
}


xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You say the addresses are in a file that are updated every couple of hours - if you don't check which addresses are updated and you (re-)geocode all of them, this could push you over your limit.

Comment: I dont geocode all of them. I get the address i need from the file based on a search criteria.

Comment: Do you track how many you're geocoding?

Comment: No but i'm the only one using it and no way in hell am i reaching 2500 queries.

Answer (score 3):

Reading documentation about [google maps.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits), you can see that

> If you exceed the usage limits you will get an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status code as a response.
>
> This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses and switch to returning only status code `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` until more usage is allowed again. This can happen:
>
> 1. Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your
>      application sent too many requests per second.
> 2. Some time in the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The time of day at which the daily quota for a service is reset varies between customers and for each API, and can change over time.
>
> Upon receiving a response with status code `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second.

**Based on what you told** most probably you already used your daily limit.

Based on their [licensing policy](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing) you can get 2500 request for geocoding.

Comment: I only sent 20 queries today. And i'm pausing 2 seconds between each query.

Comment: @user1721803 Seems that, 2 seconds isn't enough. Google still thinks, their service is abused as they think that they shouldn't be receive requests from same IP within so short time intervals in normal usage. Make it 10 seconds, 20 seconds, try with bigger timeouts. Geocoding is a sensitive service for Google I think.

Comment: I made it wait for 10 seconds and it still isnt working. And this problem always start first thing in the morning. When no one has used it for at least 16 hours.

Comment: I have a 2 second delay, am not exceeding the limit, and am having this problem as well (over_query_limit). Sometimes it works, but a lot of the time is doesn't.  Maybe they are using some kind of algorithm to determine abuse which they aren't telling us about?